# How to get certain string out of EditText

Tags: android, kotlin

I need to get a certain String out of an EditText.

Lets say user copy-paste this text to my app, to editText. The is always some text goes first(number of lines may be different), then always 2 dots like this ** and after that goes  liene of usefull text 1, then enter (empty line), then useful text 2 and so on

"sometest sometext sometet
sgjpj some text some text

**

line of useful text 1

line of useful text 2

line of useful text 3"

How can I get lines of useful text only and save it somewhere (ex. `listOf<String>`)?

Comment: Google regex, might be useful in your case, or if you are sure about the pattern and that '**' do not appear anymore after 'useful lines' then you can search the string for the last occurrence of '**' and take substring after found index.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `.split()` and `.replace()` functions.

```
val text = "sometest sometext sometet sgjpj some text 
some text

**

line of usefull text 1

line of useful text 2

line of useful text 3"

val usefulText: List<String> = text.replace("\n", "").split("**")
usefulText.forEach {
    println(it)
}
```